# Net Present Value Function Using List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

For Lists and tuples I've been able to do the same thing to find NPV

```
cash_flow_list_of_lists = [[1, 200], [4, 500], [7, 1600]]
```

## Compute and print the present value as per above

```
NPV=sum([cash_flow/(1.1**year) for year,cash_flow in 
cash_flow_list_of_lists])
print("Present Value = " , (f"{NPV:9,.2f}"))
```

How do I do this with a dictionary list

```
cash_flow_dictionary = {1: 200, 4: 500, 7: 1600}
```

## Compute and print the present value as per above

I tried 
    NPV=sum([cash_flow_dictionary.values()]/(1.1**cash_flow_dictionary.keys()) in cash_flow_dictionary)

But I have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is provided below:

```
NPVDict = sum([cash_flow/(1.1**year) for year,cash_flow in
cash_flow_dictionary.items()]) # Note items function to iterate over dictionary
print("Present Value = " , (f"{NPVDict:9,.2f}"))
```

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: OMG YOURE THE BEST THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: If it helps,  please upvote and mark the answer as answered.